# Use Ti.UI.SIZE in dp instead of pixels in Titanium

Tags: android, user-interface, titanium

I want to use `Ti.UI.SIZE` in dp (density-independent pixel) instead of pixels to support all android different resolutions, I have an imageView that gets its image from a url, so I don't know what is the width or height of the image and therefore I set them to `Ti.UI.SIZE`, it works well on iphone but the problem is in android.

So, is there anyway to use `Ti.UI.SIZE` in dp not in pixels ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The image's actual size is absolute so dp versus pixels does not make sense. It seems like you instead want to scale the image (which will look crappy) or redesign the android interface.

Comment: I think this is wrong, one of the tests I made is putting an image that I know it's size, if I just put it without dp, it deals with measures as pixels and shown in smaller size, if I typed their width and height and ended them with dp like `width: "148dp", height: "100dp"`, they are shown in the size I need, or they have the same appearance in iphone.

Comment: An image has an absolute size. Therefore it will look smaller on higher resolution screens if shown unscaled, [this is an obvious fact](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence). If you specify an image size in density independent pixels on a high resolution screen, the image will scale up, if you specify it in dp on a non-retina iphone it will be the same, ie. unscaled.

Comment: You can change `<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">px</property>` to `<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>` in TiApp.xml. Note : It'll make default unit to dp from pixel

Comment: That works fine, thanks a lot, I changed the defaultunit to dp instead of px and that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good solution is to make 'dp' your default unit instead of pixels.

Just open tiapp.xml the string 'system' or 'px' to 'dp'...

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">system</property>
```

change it to

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
```